# NavigationBar BackgroundColor Flash When Push/Pop Controller

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationbar

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDoW1.gif)

When i Push a Controller , The navigationBar's backgroundColor will Flash, but when i present a login Controller before, the navigationBar's background don't Flash, how can i keep no flash without present the login Controller?? and why cause the issuse?

Comment: pushViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed=YES;

Comment: Sorry i type the Wrong word , it's NavigationBar  not TabBar

Comment: who.....can ....help ....me   :<